# Getting value from IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#

There are some problems here:

1) Firstly, I've a property in Class1

```
class Class1
{
    IEnumerable itemSource;

    public IEnumerable ItemSource
    {
        set { itemSource = value; }
        get { return itemSource; }
    }
}
```

2) a class named `TempClass`

```
public class TempClass
{
    int a;
    public int A
    {
        set { a = value; }
        get { return a; }
    }

    public TempClass() { }
    public TempClass(int t) { A = t; }
}
```

3) In `static void Main(string[] args)`, I tried to this:

```
ObservableCollection<TempClass> test = new ObservableCollection<TempClass>
{
    new TempClass(1),
    new TempClass(2),
    new TempClass(3)
}

Class1 class1 = new Class1();
class1.ItemSource = test;

foreach (var item in class1.ItemSource)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

4) Then, the console shows this:

```
testSolution.TempClass
testSolution.TempClass
testSolution.TempClass
```

where `testSolution` is my solution name, so is a name of the namespace.

I want to get values: 1, 2, 3.

Here, what I want to make is a property and method that show values of any collection or list of any class type.

In this case, ItemSource property and method that has:

```
foreach (var item in class1.ItemSource)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: `IEnumerable<?>` what is the type of IEnumerable in class1 ? Am I to assume of Type `TempClass`? or simply `IEnumerable<T> where T:Class`?

Comment: no.. I have to make a method with premise I do not know the type, in this case TempClass. So first I have to find the properties of type

Comment: You got to use reflection for this , however it wold be nice to know the Type of collection am working on?

Comment: but I don't know the type of collection. The example class above, TempClass, is just example. I have to prepare for any type of collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may need modification, am just laying out an idea on how to use reflection when the type and properties are unknown. *I did not test this code,so feel free to modify*

```
foreach(var objUnknown in ItemSource) {
    foreach(var prop in objUnknown.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(objUnknown, null));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
foreach (var item in class1.ItemSource)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((TempClass)item).A);
}
```

Second option is, Overriding as the other answer suggests, change the class definition as like this :

```
public class TempClass
{
   int a;
   public int A
   {
       set { a = value; }
       get { return a; }
   }
   public TempClass() { }
   public TempClass(int t) { A = t; }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       return A.ToString();
   }
}
```

And print the value like this:

```
foreach (var item in class1.ItemSource)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Note : You need not to know about the class or properties when iterate over the `class1.ItemSource` use overrided `.ToString()` method in each class and print Return what you wished to print on the screen, Lets have another example here:

```
public class student
 {
     public int id { get; set; }
     public String fName { get; set; }
     public String lName { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return String.Format("Student ID : {0} \n Full Name : {1} {2}", id, fName, lName);
     }
 }
```

Here in this case the `item.ToString()` will prints the `Student ID : 1 
Full Name : suji vasuki`

Comment: the point is that I don't know 'A'. I don't know the type and also properties

Answer (score 1):

You would need this in `TempClass`:

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return A.ToString();
        }
```

For a generic solution, you would need constraint:

```
    public class Class1<T> where T : Temp
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> ItemSource
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void WriteLine()
        {
            foreach (var item in ItemSource)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.A);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Temp
    {
        public abstract int A { get; set; }
    }

    public class TempClass : Temp
    {
        public override int A
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public TempClass(int t) { A = t; }
    }
```

to write the property A:

```
        ObservableCollection<TempClass> test = new ObservableCollection<TempClass>
        {
            new TempClass(1),
            new TempClass(2),
            new TempClass(3)
        };

        Class1<TempClass> class1 = new Class1<TempClass>();
        class1.ItemSource = test;
        class1.WriteLine();
```

Comment: the point is that I don't know 'A'. I don't know the type and also properties

Comment: éc, did you mean you even don't know `TempClass`?

Comment: yes, I should make a method with a fact that I don't know the type of collection or list

Comment: Then the element type of the collection `ItemSource` should be generic and must comply some constraints like it must have a property `A`.

Comment: oh.. I learned a lot from your answer! there are so many to study. thank you!!